# Error when Select database after getting value from ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I use js to get user "name" and send it to result.php by ajax.

in result.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'] //name contain string

// Then I want to select information from that user "name"
$result2 = $db->query('SELECT story FROM `user_story` WHERE name='.$name) or error('failed', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
```

But why doesn't it work?

Can anybody explain this to me and provide a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you'd checked for errors/actually read the error, you'd probably get a syntax error. Strings need to be quoted. Use prepared statements with parameter binding so you don't need to worry about quoting issues.

Comment: yes, the error was same with the code I've wrote above to handle error condition (failed). Can you give me some example?

Comment: You previously had mysqli tagged, so I'd suggest [starting here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: OK thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with quotes:

```
//ADDED semicolon
$name = $_POST['name']; //name contain string 
// Then I want to select information from that user "name"
$result2 = $db->query('SELECT story FROM `user_story` WHERE name= "'.$name .  '"') or error('failed', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
```

***note:***
The best way is to use PDO prepared statements.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$result2 = $db->prepare("SELECT story FROM user_story WHERE (name = ?)");

$result2->execute(array($name));
```

Look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)